# javac not recognized java 7

Tags: java, windows-vista, javac

I have recently installed jdk7 on my windows vista.  I have used default installation in `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\` with `javac` stored in `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\bin`.  I have configured my `PATH` and `CLASSPATH` environmental variables (both for my user and system variables) with `C:\Program_Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin` and `JAVA_HOME` (as my user variable) with C`:\Program_Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\` (I have also tried a version with `C:\Program_Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\bin`).

`java -version` produces desired output.  I can also run `javac` from the `C:\Program_Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin` directory with no problem.  However when I try to run it from somewhere else I got the error that it is not recognized.  Where can be the problem.  Am I missing anything?

Comment: hi, is this a typo or is your `PATH` configured to `C:\Program_Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin` instead of `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\bin`?

Comment: yes this was the problem

Answer (score 4):

Open a command-line window, type "**path**" and check if "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\bin" is listed. If not try setting the path in that window (just to check if it works): "set path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\bin\" and try running "javac" again.

Comment: Yes it was listed.  However I tried to set it using the command you have provided and it worked.  Thank you for help wonder what was the problem.

Comment: So, maybe there is more than 1 version of JDK/Javac in the path settings and the system is confused as to which is the right 'javac'?!?!

Comment: No there is one version of JDK listed there.

Comment: But problem with this solution is that I need to run command "set path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\bin\" each time I open a new shell window

Answer (score 3):

Do check properly in your path variables, you must have kept a space somewhere, else it must run. Do check properly, something is wrong while setting up path and classpath variables. Like for example, Your path variable already has something like say C:\Apache\bin\servlet-api.jar, now since you adding java to it you might have kept one space like

```
C:\Apache\bin\servlet-api.jar; C:\Program_Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin
```

you have to remove that space, and do it like this

```
C:\Apache\bin\servlet-api.jar;C:\Program_Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin
```

Do check properly, you must have left some space(gap) somewhere

Example :

```
Variable : JAVA_HOME
Value : C:\Program_Files\Java\jdk1.7.0

Variable : PATH
Value : %JAVA_HOME%\bin
```

Now open cmd, and type echo %JAVA_HOME%
This must show your location to JAVA_HOME as set before.

**EDIT : I have configured my PATH environmental variables (both for my user and  system variables) with C:\Program_Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin and JAVA_HOME (as my user    variable) with C:\Program_Files\Java\jdk1.7.0**

**   But before that you are saying that your java is installed at this location**

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\bin
```

**why this different location, you are setting it for jdk1.7.0 but you said it's inside jdk1.7.0_02.**

Hope that might help

Regards

Comment: No it wasn't that there were no spaces

Comment: But do look at my edit, you were saying your installed path is C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\bin and you set your classpath and path variable for C:\Program_Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin why this mismatch in jdk folder name one is using the _02 as extension and the other one without it.  Regards

Answer (score 1):

You have an underscore in your entries that were put in the PATH variable.  This will not work correctly.

Comment: underscore works in PATH variable, I am also using `_` in my system

Comment: I tried different versions with and without underscore.  Some older versions of windows required underscore.